# What is the best way to reduce computation time when processing a big data frame?

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a big data frame consisting of 9 mio objects in RStudio server with the following format (there are many readings for each installnr) and when I am running a script calculating the means and standard error bars of all the readings per hour, R crashes. What is the best way to avoid huge computation times and exceeding memory size?

```
       installnr readdate   readings
    1    002345 2014-08-17 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0}
    2    002345 2014-08-18 {0,0,0,0,0,0,4,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1}
    3    002345 2014-08-19 {0,1,2,1,0,1,1,1,2,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,2,1,1,0}
    4    013459 2014-08-17 {1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,3,1,0,0,1,1}
    5    127465 2014-08-19 {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1}
```

An example of the script I am running is the following:

```
df$readings = gsub("[{}]", "", as.character(df$readings))
Read1 = strsplit(df$readings, ",")
Readings = matrix(as.numeric(unlist(Read1)), nrow=length(Read1))
colMeans(Readings)
```

Comment: Try using `data.table` or `dplyr`

Comment: The matrix you're creating is too large, that's why you run out of memory.  If you are just interested in the mean, loop over each row and keep a running total of each column.  Divide by nrow(df) at the end.

Comment: I have been just using read.csv to import the full data frame...

Comment: @peny - can you provide a few lines of your raw text as well? Handling some of the initial conversion outside of R might actually make more sense.

Comment: "R crashes". What does that mean? Is this in Windows? Errors?, Segfaults?

Comment: Quick tip: create a smaller object to work with and run it through a profiler like profvis (https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/). This will help you locate issues and work on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to stick to your input format, here is a solution that might work for you.

**First**, install and load packages `stringr` and `data.table`.

**Second**, extract numbers from readings and create data table:

```
dt <- data.table(str_extract_all(df$readings,"[0-9]+", simplify=TRUE))
```

Note that the regular expression `[0-9]+` assumes integer values.

**Third**, convert entire data table from chr to numeric:

```
dt <- dt[, lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]
```

Now, use `dt[, lapply(.SD, mean)]` to calculate the mean of each individual column.

You could also use `lapply(dt, mean)`, of course.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot install data.table on R server, as the file or directory does not exist according to the error message. Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the precise error message. It would be best to open a separate question if there is none yet.

Comment: unfortunately the proposed code does not work either because R cannot allocate vector of that size (19.5 Gb!). Any other suggestions?

Comment: you could divide the file into multiple smaller chunks, process each as suggested, and use e.g. `data.table::rbindlist` to merge the intermediate data.tables